# CSS Drop-down menu enlarges the parent width, when on hover action

Tags: html, css

I have the following Html file, together with the CSS file. When I hover over the Main Navigation bar to open the drop-down menu, the parent width enlarges together with the drop-down menu. How can I fix this? If I set position: absolute to the dropdown menu, it will not work at all.(hovering doesn't trigger the dropdown). I have put my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/L67oxmqc/2/   .
Thank you!

Code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
h1 {
  color: navy;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
/* SECTION WITH THE heading text */

#boldtext {
  color: Black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #a9bcba;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
/* SECTION WITH BILL GATES QUOTE */

#quotetext {
  color: Black;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
div.quote {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  /* border: 2px solid rgb(150,245,255);
     opacity: 0.8;*/
}
/* SECTION WITH THE MENU FOR THE MAIN PAGE */

div.menu ul {
  border-radius: 05px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #a9bcba;
  /*z-index: -1; */
}
div.menu li {
  float: left;
}
div.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
div.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #879694;
  color: blue;
}
/* SECTION WITH THE DROPDOWN CONTENT FOR THE MENU */

.dropdowncontent a:hover {
  background-color: #cbd6d5
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdowncontent {
  display: block;
}
div.dropdowncontent {
  display: none;
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: #a9bcba;
  width: 115px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
div.dropdowncontent a {
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<br>
<!-- Header -->

<b id="boldtext">Welcome</b>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- Menu bar-->

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="default.asp">Boeing Family</a>
      <div class="dropdowncontent">
        <a href="#">Boeing 737 class</a>
        <a href="#">Boeing 747 class</a>
        <a href="#">Boeing 787 class</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">Airbus Family</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Others</a>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="about.asp">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <!-- The Contact button is set to be on the right side of the Navigation bar-->
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="quote" id="quotetext">
  <p><q><cite>A generic quote.</q>
    </cite>

    — Author.</p>
</div>

<!-- Boeing planes image that triggers the Boeing menu-->
<a href="Boeing.htm" </a>
  <img src="Boeing-777-Generic-Nice.jpg" alt="Boeing picture" style="width:350px;height:150px;">


  <!-- Airbus planes image that triggers the Airbus menu-->

  <a href="Airbus.htm" </a>
    <img src="A320-generic.jpg" alt="Airbus picture" style="width:350px;height:150px;">

    <!-- ATR planes image that triggers the ATR menu-->

    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATR_(aircraft_manufacturer)" </a>
      <img src="ATR_generic.jpg" alt="Airbus picture" style="width:350px;height:150px;">

      <!-- Link to the Frequently asked questions page-->

      <a href=#>
        <img src="question.jpg" alt="question image" style="width:350px;height:150px;">
      </a>

      <br>
      <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle of the solution I mention below: https://jsfiddle.net/2sy0dn6w/

Fixing your solution is incredibly simple. You want to use `position: absolute;` for your `div.dropdowncontent` CSS class. You also want to make your parent `li` tag have `position: relative;` to keep your `div.dropdowncontent` constrained within the parent `li`. And then you have an issue with your primary `ul` tag with using `overflow: hidden`. This would prevent your dropdown from being seen. And I understand why you are using `overflow: hidden;` - you're using it as a clearfix. But in this case, it is a problem because it hides your dropdown. So instead we would want to use `:before` with the `ul` for the clearfix. The steps for applying the fixes are below.

First, remove `overflow: hidden;` from your css for `div.menu ul {}`. This will create the following:

```
div.menu ul {
    border-radius: 05px;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    background-color: #a9bcba;
    /*z-index: -1; */
    }
```

Next, right after the `div.menu ul {}` CSS, add:

```
div.menu > ul::after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: ' ';
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Lastly, at the very bottom of your CSS, add the following (you can even move each of the below to their designated declarations you already have in your CSS. The reason I'm adding this separate is so that it's more obvious what I included to give you the outcome you're looking for):

```
div.menu > ul > li {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdowncontent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

li.dropdown:hover div.dropdowncontent {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How to adjust the CSS for positioning if the pop up menu is under 2nd element not 1st element?

Comment: Based on the last declaration, just add .dropdown to your lower level, and it will trigger `display: block` for `.dropdowncontent`. All you'll need to modify is the first declaration `div.menu > ul > li` to `div.menu ul li`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just update in your style may it works for you

```
div.menu ul {
    background-color: #a9bcba;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

div.dropdowncontent {
    background-color: #a9bcba;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 115px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below

Remove overflow hidden

```
div.menu ul{
   ...
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add position absolute

```
div.dropdowncontent {
   ...
   position: absolute;
}
```

replace float left

```
div.menu li{
    /* float: left; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
h1 {
  color: navy;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
/* SECTION WITH THE heading text */

#boldtext {
  color: Black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #a9bcba;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
/* SECTION WITH BILL GATES QUOTE */

#quotetext {
  color: Black;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
div.quote {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  /* border: 2px solid rgb(150,245,255);
     opacity: 0.8;*/
}
/* SECTION WITH THE MENU FOR THE MAIN PAGE */

div.menu ul {
  border-radius: 05px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px; 
  background-color: #a9bcba;
  /*z-index: -1; */
}
div.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
div.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: white;
}
div.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #879694;
  color: blue;
}
/* SECTION WITH THE DROPDOWN CONTENT FOR THE MENU */

.dropdowncontent a:hover {
  background-color: #cbd6d5
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdowncontent {
  display: block;
}
div.dropdowncontent {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a9bcba;
  width: 115px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
div.dropdowncontent a {
  color: red;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<br>
<!-- Header -->

<b id="boldtext">Welcome</b>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- Menu bar-->

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="default.asp">Boeing Family</a>
      <div class="dropdowncontent">
        <a href="#">Boeing 737 class</a>
        <a href="#">Boeing 747 class</a>
        <a href="#">Boeing 787 class</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">Airbus Family</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Others</a>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="about.asp">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <!-- The Contact button is set to be on the right side of the Navigation bar-->
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="quote" id="quotetext">
  <p><q><cite>A generic quote.</q>
    </cite>

    — Author.</p>
</div>

<!-- Boeing planes image that triggers the Boeing menu-->
<a href="Boeing.htm" </a>
  <img src="Boeing-777-Generic-Nice.jpg" alt="Boeing picture" style="width:350px;height:150px;">


  <!-- Airbus planes image that triggers the Airbus menu-->

  <a href="Airbus.htm" </a>
    <img src="A320-generic.jpg" alt="Airbus picture" style="width:350px;height:150px;">

    <!-- ATR planes image that triggers the ATR menu-->

    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATR_(aircraft_manufacturer)" </a>
      <img src="ATR_generic.jpg" alt="Airbus picture" style="width:350px;height:150px;">

      <!-- Link to the Frequently asked questions page-->

      <a href=#>
        <img src="question.jpg" alt="question image" style="width:350px;height:150px;">
      </a>

      <br>
      <br>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I just followed your suggestions and the dropdown works as I expect now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use position absolute, you cant see it working because ul has overflow:hidden;

add this css :

```
.menu ul{
    overflow:visible;
}
.menu ul li.dropdown{
    position : relative;
}
.menu ul li.dropdown .dropdowncontent{
    position : absolute;
    top:38px;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css:

add .menu class  and remove bg-color from ul

```
.menu {
  background-color: #a9bcba;
  height: 45px;
}

div.menu ul {
    border-radius: 05px;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    //background-color: #a9bcba; <--- remove background
    /*z-index: -1; */
}
```